# Duplicity Backup Browse

Tags: duplicity

I have made a duplicity backup with Ubuntu 14.04 in another laptop of my home directory.

I copied all duplicity back files to my current laptop to "/home/user/Ubuntu-backup"

How do i browse the content of that backup see if it is worth restoring?
I want to restore how do i restore from those files.

Answer (score 12):

`man duplicity` is your friend.

To list files contained in a backup,

`duplicity list-current-files [options] [--time time] target_url`

Start of sample output:

```
Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.
Last full backup date: Thu Apr 20 07:05:12 2017
Tue May 16 10:59:53 2017 .
Tue Oct  4 09:17:44 2016 home
Wed May 24 12:25:20 2017 home/[username]
Tue Feb 16 19:41:10 2016 home/[username]/.ICEauthority
Thu Apr 21 20:43:49 2016 home/[username]/.Skype
Fri Jul 11 15:50:50 2014 home/[username]/.Skype/DataRv
```

Another useful status command

`duplicity collection-status [options] [--file-changed <relpath>] target_url`

Start of sample output:

```
Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.
Last full backup date: Thu Apr 20 07:05:12 2017
Collection Status
-----------------
Connecting with backend: BackendWrapper
Archive dir: /home/[username]/.cache/duplicity/4d2fe5a2e1ead3bd31ee9829cdc85731

Found 9 secondary backup chains.
Secondary chain 1 of 9:
-------------------------
Chain start time: Tue Jul 29 09:17:49 2014
Chain end time: Fri Jan  9 08:04:33 2015
Number of contained backup sets: 22
Total number of contained volumes: 47
 Type of backup set:                            Time:      Num volumes:
                Full         Tue Jul 29 09:17:49 2014                17
         Incremental         Fri Aug  1 18:57:47 2014                10
         Incremental         Fri Aug  8 10:14:40 2014                 1
         Incremental         Sat Aug 16 08:29:10 2014                 1
         Incremental         Fri Aug 22 18:41:56 2014                 1
         Incremental         Fri Aug 29 11:36:42 2014                 1
         Incremental         Fri Sep  5 13:03:08 2014                 1
         Incremental         Fri Sep 12 07:45:14 2014                 1
         Incremental         Sat Sep 20 19:50:22 2014                 1
         Incremental         Sat Oct 11 08:06:38 2014                 1
         Incremental         Fri Oct 17 06:57:46 2014                 1
         Incremental         Fri Oct 24 07:56:08 2014                 1
         Incremental         Fri Oct 31 07:39:11 2014                 1
         Incremental         Fri Nov  7 07:28:01 2014                 1
         Incremental         Fri Nov 14 07:50:54 2014                 1
         Incremental         Thu Nov 20 20:29:11 2014                 1
         Incremental         Wed Nov 26 19:37:13 2014                 1
         Incremental         Thu Dec  4 15:37:21 2014                 1
         Incremental         Thu Dec 11 12:32:11 2014                 1
         Incremental         Fri Dec 19 05:59:36 2014                 1
         Incremental         Thu Jan  1 19:05:41 2015                 1
         Incremental         Fri Jan  9 08:04:33 2015                 1
-------------------------
```

To restore files

`duplicity [restore] [options] [--file-to-restore <relpath>] [--time
       time] source_url target_directory`

Comment: Is there any GUI for that?