# Deja Dup - last run results?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I'm still in search of a good backup scheme for my Xubuntu 18.04 machine.
In looking at Deja Dup (aka Backups), it seems dead simple and it said it successfully backed up my data. And it runs once a day.

- But exactly when does it run once a day?
- What were the results of the last run?
- Did it even run today? Were
  there errors? Where are they logged?

It's interface might be a little too simple.
Any ideas on where to find at least the info above? I tried this:

```
DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1 deja-dup --backup
```

Not sure this is the answer - I just want to check in on it every once in a while to make sure all is well.

Comment: There are some options on the command line tool `duplicity` (which deja-dup is a front end for) that give status.  See if this helps you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/918926/duplicity-backup-browse/918936#918936  You might like the `collection-status` option.

Comment: This did the trick:
'duplicity collection-status file:///mnt/user/linux/dejadup'